# Flutter Image Widget won't update on change state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am creating an Image Editor application using sliders, something like Instagram, and I am using library image/image.dart.
The problem is that once you move the slider it updates the image but just that time, if you move it again, it won't update.

I have set everything as expected, setState() functions as flutter asks, but I don't know why it won't update again.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:image/image.dart' as br;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ImageManager extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ImageManagerState();
  }
}

class _ImageManagerState extends State<ImageManager> {
  File imageFile;
  br.Image image;
  Image _imageWidget;

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  // get tmp file
  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/tmp.jpg');
  }

  // pick image on button click
  Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async{
    File selectedFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    br.Image selectedImage;
    if (selectedFile != null){
      selectedImage = br.decodeImage(selectedFile.readAsBytesSync());
      br.grayscale(selectedImage);

      selectedFile.writeAsBytesSync(br.encodeJpg(selectedImage));
    }

    setState((){
      image = selectedImage;
      imageFile = selectedFile;
      _imageWidget = Image.file(imageFile);
    });
  }

  // MAIN PROBLEM, UPDATING THE CONTRAST WILL ONLY DO IT ONCE
  Future<void> updateContrast(value) async{
    File contrastFile = imageFile;
    br.Image contrast = br.decodeImage(contrastFile.readAsBytesSync());
    contrast = br.adjustColor(contrast, contrast: value);
    contrastFile.writeAsBytesSync(br.encodeJpg(contrast));

    // Save the thumbnail as a jpg.
    File path = await _localFile;
    path.writeAsBytesSync(br.encodeJpg(contrast));
    setState(() {
      image = contrast;
      imageFile = contrastFile;
      if(path != null){
        _imageWidget = Image.file(path);
        print(value);
      }

    });
  }

  // 
  Widget _buildImage(BuildContext context){
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: _imageWidget,
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // contrast
                  Text("Contraste"),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0, top: 0.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Slider(
                        min: 0.0,
                        max: 1.0,
                        divisions: 100,
                        value: _contrast,
                        activeColor: Colors.blue[500],
                        inactiveColor: Colors.blue[50],
                        label: "${(_contrast *100).round()}",
                        onChanged: (value) async{
                          changeContrast(value);
                        },
                        onChangeEnd: (value) async{
                          updateContrast(value);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
```

I expect the image to update every time the slider is changed.

Comment: where is the method `changeContrast` you are using ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to upload but it is just a function that set the variable _contrast to the current value on the slider.

Comment: and do you call setState there?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not adding that part, it goes like this: ```void changeContrast(contrast){
    setState(() => _contrast = contrast);
  }```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue, which is pretty weird to me, but if someone can explain it, I would appreciate it.

```
Future<void> adjustImage() async{
  File toAdjustFile = imageFile;
  br.Image toAdjust = br.decodeImage(toAdjustFile.readAsBytesSync());
  toAdjust = br.adjustColor(toAdjust, contrast: _contrast, brightness: _brightness, exposure: _exposure);
  setState(() {
    _imageWidget = Image.memory(br.encodeJpg(toAdjust));
  });
}
```

I refactored my function and set the widget to another constructor, `Image.memory()`.

Comment: I have a similar situation... it's just an image selection (gallery/camera) with an `Image.file` to show the selected picture. When the images has changed, the `Image.file` don't update and always shows the same result. Your solution with `Image.memory` works for me. I believe that the `Image.file` uses some cache and don't refresh the images.

Comment: Yeah, I actually had to do the same with the selection of the image, since it will not update correctly, had to use the `Image.memory` too, hope it worked for you.

Comment: Issue is still open https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17419

Comment: So, Image.file() uses ResizeImage.resizeIfNeeded() which in turn uses FileImage() which is the provider for the image data. The FileImage.hashCode() method uses `int get hashCode => hashValues(file?.path, scale);` As such, when chaning the path of an image file I believe its at this point that it fails. (I'm assuming the hasCode is used to detect if the file is dirty and needs reloading). 

Conversely, Image.memory uses MemoryImage whose hashcode is based on the bytes of the image. As such it will detect a change.

Answer (score 6):

`imageCache.clear()` will do the job.

I was also not able to reload the image to save locally on the screen. From debugging, I observed the old image is in fact deleted, and new image is copied there, but nothing was changing on the screen. Following is the code you need.

So, in the body of `Scaffold`, I have made a `FutureBuilder` that calls another function `reload()`, which then loads the file and return the image.

```
FutureBuilder(
future: reload(),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
        return snapshot.data;
    }  
    else{
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
},
),
```

Here is the `reload()` function:

```
reload() async {
String path = "path of your image";
File profileImage = File("$path/name.jpg");

if(profileImage.existsSync() == false){
  return Text("File Not Found");
}
else{
  imageCache.clear();
  return Image.file(profileImage);
}
}
```

I checked Flutter's github, and [jamesncl has already suggested this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17419#issuecomment-549919627).

Answer (score 2):

Use Image.memory instaead Image.file, A line from my code

```
Image.memory(
          File(widget.imagePath).readAsBytesSync(),),
```

Comment: Thanks mate This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just added `UniqueKey` to `ListView`.

```
            child: ListView(
              key: UniqueKey(),
```